# Disable all sundays except mother day

Tags: javascript, html, flatpickr

I want to disable all sundays in flatpickr, thats working correctly. But now I want do define some exceptions e.g. mother day. This is my code, but the if-block will always be executed and I still can not select mother's day.

```
   // Mothers Day -> dd.mm.yyyy
   const d = new Date();
   d.setMonth(4); // May
   d.setDate(8); // May 8 is the earliest possible date
   // while not a sunday, move to next day
   while (d.getUTCDay()) d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
   const motherDayDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('de-DE', { day: "2-digit", month: "2-digit", year: "numeric"}).format(d);

  $(".datePicker").flatpickr({
    enableTime: false,
    dateFormat: "d.m.Y",
    minDate: "today",
    "locale": {
        "firstDayOfWeek": 1
    },
    "disable": [
        function(date) {
            //  motherDayDate = e.g. 09.05.2021
            if (moment(date).format("DD.MM.YYYY") === motherDayDate){
                alert ("mother");
                return true;
            }
            
            // 0 = Sunday
            return (date.getDay() === 0);
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: `motherDayDate` doesn't appear to be set anywhere. If you are setting it, please include that in your example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with flatpickr, but perhaps you should be returning `false` below the code `alert("mother");`?

(I would have posted this as a comment if I had enough reputation. Hope this helps, though!)